# zurb foundation sass: "@charset may only be used at the root of a document."

Tags: sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm using the scss version of zurbs foundation framework.

I'm importing secondary stylesheets into my main stylesheet within media queries, like this:

```
  @media all and (min-width: 768px) 
    @import tablet
```

I'm importing foundations files into both my primary and tablet stylesheets like this:

```
@import "foundation"
@import "foundation/components/grid"
@import "foundation/components/_buttons"
@import "foundation/components/_clearing"
@import "foundation/components/_type"
```

However, when I add the tablet sass file into my primary sass file via the mq, I get this error:

```
error foundation.scss (Line 3: @charset may only be used at the root of a document.)
```

The source of this error appears to be in line 3 of foundation.scss:

```
@charset "UTF-8"
```

However, if I remove this line, then the characterset doesn't get declared.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason both primary and tablet files need to import the entirety of foundation?  Can't you just import them outside if your media query?

Comment: As far as I am aware, I need to import foundations files into any file from which I intend to use foundation. Failing to do so results in errors that indicate that foundation files are not available.

Comment: Considering all `@import "foundation"` does is import a file that imports a bunch of other files, you do not need to import the entire library.